# ArcPy Pandas export spatial data frame to feature class

Tags: arcpy, pandas, data-frame, typeerror

I am successfully creating two data frames with ArcPy and Pandas, 1) from an enterprise geodatabase feature class and 2) from an enterprise geodatabase table, then merging them into 3) data frame that I need to export to a file geodatabase.  Df #3 will export if I pass the merged df directly, but it only exports 256 polygons of 11k records.
left_merged.spatial.to_featureclass(location=new_Table, overwrite=True)

If I convert the merged data frame to a spatially enabled data frame then try to export, it gives an error ‘float’ type is not iterable.
sedf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_df(left_merged,geometry_column='SHAPE')
sedf.spatial.to_featureclass(location=new_Table, overwrite=True)

As a test for the polygon shapes, I exported the 1) data frame created from the featureclass back to a feature class with spatial.to_featureclass successfully to a 285k polygon layer in a fgdb.

All my searches are not finding an answer.  Does anyone have any suggestions to try?  Including more code and the dataframe shapes below.  Greatly appreciate any thoughts.

```py
featureClassDF = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass(sde_fc)
featureClassDFshape = featureClassDF.head
print(featureClassDFshape)

joinTableDF = table_to_data_frame(sde_table, input_fields=None, where_clause=None)
joinTableDFshape = joinTableDF.head
print(joinTableDFshape)

left_merged = pd.merge(joinTableDF, featureClassDF,how="left", right_on="KEY1", left_on="KEY2")
rightMergeDFshape = left_merged.head
print(rightMergeDFshape)

sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_df(left_merged, geometry_column='SHAPE')
sdf.spatial.to_featureclass(location=new_Table)
```

RETURNS ERROR

```
sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_df(left_merged, geometry_column='SHAPE')
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo\_accessor.py", line 2515, in from_df
    df[geometry_column] = GeoArray(df[geometry_column].apply(Geometry))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4138, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\geometry\_types.py", line 254, in __call__
    elif "coordinates" in iterable:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

RESULTS FROM TH READING THE HEADERS

```
COMPLETE Step 1: Create Dataframe from enterprise geodatabase feature class : 
<bound method NDFrame.head of         OBJECTID  ...                                              SHAPE
0         343248  ...  {"rings": [[[2297102.5921444204, 1444228.53548...
1         343249  ...  {"rings": [[[2287200.746140709, 1444119.373943...
2         343251  ...  {"rings": [[[2285734.7906778734, 1444221.64314...
3         343252  ...  {"rings": [[[2293205.9998777825, 1447948.87538...
4         343253  ...  {"rings": [[[2291248.000339614, 1447874.499946...
...          ...  ...                                                ...
287389    546304  ...  {"rings": [[[2355944.2357354257, 1460409.92918...
287390    546311  ...  {"rings": [[[2355741.433648469, 1460418.583619...
287391    546835  ...  {"rings": [[[2355773.0164330285, 1460709.38121...
287392    773576  ...  {"rings": [[[2365875.16462761, 1403794.3848832...
287393    776575  ...  {"rings": [[[2365768.1812394727, 1403689.79407...

[287394 rows x 21 columns]>
Creating dataframe from SDE Table
START Step 2: Create Dataframe from SDE Table : 
COMPLETE Step 2: Create Dataframe from SDE Table : 
<bound method NDFrame.head of                  B1_ALT_ID  ...                                      ACA_DEEP_LINK
OBJECTID                    ...                                                   
1         RESBLD2020-00090  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
2         RESBLD2020-00091  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
3         RESBLD2020-00092  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
4         RESBLD2020-00093  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
5         RESBLD2020-00094  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
...                    ...  ...                                                ...
11331     RESBLD2023-00956  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
11332     RESBLD2023-00957  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
11333     RESBLD2023-00958  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
11334     COMBLD2023-00745  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...
11335     RESBLD2023-00959  ...  https://Cap/CapDe...

[11888 rows x 31 columns]>
Creating joined dataframe
START Step 3: Create left merge Dataframe : 
COMPLETE Step 3: Create left merge Dataframe : 
<bound method NDFrame.head of               B1_ALT_ID  ...                                              SHAPE
0      2020-00090  ...  {'curveRings': [[[2317338.4638255034, 1457925....
1      2020-00091  ...  {'rings': [[[2364204.418443976, 1490205.239336...
2      2020-00092  ...  {'curveRings': [[[2384600.899633972, 1458256.5...
3      2020-00093  ...  {'rings': [[[2361476.4273303133, 1483584.46221...
4      2020-00094  ...  {'curveRings': [[[2373245.34664456, 1405170.62...
...                 ...  ...                                                ...
11884  2023-00956  ...                                                NaN
11885  2023-00957  ...                                                NaN
11886  2023-00958  ...                                                NaN
11887  2023-00745  ...  {'curveRings': [[[2312112.5297758374, 1441232....
11888  2023-00959  ...  {'rings': [[[2363987.784509523, 1496937.498512...

[11889 rows x 52 columns]>
```

Comment: I was able to find that df.spatial.to_featureclass(location=) will not skip empty SHAPE values when exporting DF to a featureclass, it stops with the last valid shape.  My record #255 was an invalid SHAPE, so the export was only 254 records.  This confirms that all 3 DFs were indeed valid, so I filtered out the bad shapes and got all valid records exported.

Comment: Still do not understand why creating a SEDF from the merged DF returns the error: argument of type 'float' is not iterable